# Using SimpleHtmlDom, how to remove and replace a specific attribute

Tags: php, parsing, simple-html-dom

I'm currently using this HTML DOM PARSER using php : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I'm confused on how to remove and replace the selected attribute `href="style.css"`, I want to replace the link with `"index/style.css"`, should I insert only the

> index/

or replace the whole attribute from the whole html code?

Comment: why not use the native PHP DOM parser?

Comment: what do you mean native PHP DOM PARSER?

Comment: @dqhendricks The PHP DOM library offers quite a rough feature set. There're many basic features that you need to code yourself. Third-party libraries are a good option if they're solid enough.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$doc = str_get_html($code);
foreach ($doc->find('a[href]') as $a) {
    $href = $a->href;
    if (/* $href begins with a relative URL path */) {
        $a->href = 'index/'.$href;
    }

}
$code = (string) $doc;
```

You could also use [PHP’s native DOM library](http://php.net/book.dom):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($code);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[@href]') as $a) {
    $href = $a->getAttribute('href');
    if (/* $href begins with a relative URL path */) {
        $a->setAttribute('href', 'index/'.$href);
    }
}
$code = $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 1):

The official manual has several examples that basically cover all you need:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

If you have issues with some specific step, feel free to update your question and provide some of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = str_get_html($string); 
if ($html){ // Verify connection, return False if could not load the resource
    $e = $html->find("a");
    foreach ($e as $e_element){
        $old_href = $e_element->outertext;
        // Do your modification in here 
        $e_element->href = affiliate($e_element->href); // for example I replace original link by the return of custom function named 'affiliate'
        $e_element->href = ""; //remove href
        $e_element->target .= "_blank"; // I added target _blank to open in new tab
        // end modification 
        $html = str_replace($old_href, $e_element->outertext, $html); // Update the href
    }
```