# Is it possible to extract inline CSS from HTML?

Tags: php, html, css, dom

Using http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm, is it possible to extract the inline CSS of a HTML file?

This parser if pure html, assuming (just correct me if I'm wrong) it can't parse CSS tags.Is there any other way to extract inline CSS in the html file?

Comment: Do you want to parse inline css (inside `style` elements) or inline styles (inside `style` attribute on elements).

Comment: Inline css is part of the html. It is just the contents of the `style` tag, or the value of the `style` attribute. So you should be able to get those values using an HTML parser.

Comment: inline is always referred to as inside style attributes of elements, the former would be in-document styles

Comment: can i include css parsing it using the parser?

Comment: Since you already learned how to replace attributes, you already know how to fetch the style attribute, so this is a duplicate of [Using SimpleHtmlDom, how to remove and replace a specific attribute.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600928/using-simplehtmldom-how-to-remove-and-replace-a-specific-attribute)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use simplehtmldom to extract this :

---

For

```
<style>
...
</style>
```

Use :

```
$css = $html->find('style')->innertext;
```

---

For

```
<div style="background:blue; color:white;"></div>
```

Use :

```
$css = $html->find('div[style]')->style;
```

---

If there's more than one `div` with `style` atribute or more than one `<style>`, you can use a `foreach` to loop between them.

---

To parse styles :

in PHP :

```php
$s = 'background:blue; color:white;';

$results = [];
$styles = explode(';', $s);

foreach ($styles as $style) {
    $properties = explode(':', $style);
    if (2 === count($properties)) {
        $results[trim($properties[0])] = trim($properties[1]);
    }
}

var_dump($results);
```

in JS

```js
let s = 'background:blue; color:white;';

let results = {};
let styles = s.split(";");

for (let style in styles) {
    let properties = styles[style].split(":");
  if (properties.length === 2) {
    results[properties[0].trim()] = properties[1].trim();
  }
}

console.log(results);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zyfhtwj2/

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me if I want to get only color attribute, how will I do it???

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<html><body style="color: red"></body></html>');

$els = $doc->getElementsByTagName('*');

for($i = 0; $i < $els->length; $i++)
  echo $els->item($i)->getAttribute('style'); // color: red
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a normal HTML parser:

1. Walk through all elements
2. If element's tag is `style`, get the element's content
3. If the element has an attribute `style`, get that attribute's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
find('css','div[style*="display:block;"] ')
```

That way you can find the style with attribute `display:block`. Modify this as you want and you can get inline CSS.