# How to find just relative links in dom parser

Tags: php

Just started playing with [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and I see from [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser > Modify Fetched Links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12288602/php-simple-html-dom-parser-modify-fetched-links) that it should be possible to find just the relative links to process.

My code so far:

```
<?php
include('phpsimpledom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('phpimport.html');
// to fetch all hyperlinks from a webpage
$links = array();
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) {
  $links[] = $a->href;
}
echo '<pre>', print_r($links, 1), '</pre>';
```

This prints out all the links and I only want the relative links

Comment: possible solution is in your foreach, check the first character of each string and if it's a `/` then it's an absolute link so skip it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your going through the links, check the href doesn't start with `http://` or `https://` before you add them to the list, this uses `preg_match()` to check it...

```
foreach($html->find('a') as $a) {
    if ( preg_match("/^https?:\/\//i", $a->href) === 0)   {
        $links[] = $a->href;
    }
}
```