# modify using str_replace

Tags: php

What is the easiest way to modify something with PHP. suppose `$link = http://www.example.com` so what to do to modify this link and announce it in a new variable like this> `$link_modified = http://site.com/go.html?http://www.example.com` , can i use `str_replace` in this case or any other idea?

Comment: Why do you think you cannot modify it - this does not seem to be your real question

Comment: Why would you use medium-grade artillery like str_replace, when all you're doing is a simple string concatenation?

Comment: this is why, while fetching content i wanna modify all those links URL address automatically, but can not understand how to do it.. any idea?

Comment: regex will be your best friend

Comment: @StrikeForceZero any example?

Comment: @user1642787 well regex might or might not be the answer to your situation, could you possibly explain the scenario a little bit more. As in how you want the script to run?

Comment: ok, i am using http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/ to fetch content from a site which has several links, but i dont wanna put those links directly in my website. What i wanna do, put a redirect for those links, so if there a link path, suppose `http://go.com` and i wanna change it to `www.mysite.com/visit.php?http://go.com` i know how to get those urls in simple php dom, it is something like this: `$html = str_get_html($result);
foreach($html->find('a') as $element)` but cant understand how to change or modify all Links URL's Path automatically, need your help :) Thanks

Comment: why are you asking duplicate questions? http://stackoverflow.com/q/12288602/1443717 and i found your thread over at http://www.daniweb.com/web-development/php/threads/432873/php-simple-html-dom-parser-modify-fetched-links#post1857076

Comment: this should help http://stackoverflow.com/a/4603362/1443717

Comment: @StrikeForceZero yap i also discussing it in daniweb...

Comment: dont working, i am a beginner in PHP coding, so cant fix it :( do you know any aricle or anything else?

Comment: @user1642787 posted an answer to your other question http://stackoverflow.com/a/12305353/1443717

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$link_modified = "http://site.com/go.html?" . $link;
```

or if you meant in the same var

```
$link = "http://site.com/go.html?" . $link;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like that:

```
$link = "http://www.example.com";
$link_modified = "http://site.com/go.html." . $link;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use sprintf to return a formatted string.

```
$link = 'http://www.example.com';
$link_modified = sprintf('http://site.com/go.html?%s', $link);
```